# Point in time data

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, was wondering if I can do a lookup and capture the data of the return at that point in time instead of continually updating it.

For example, if I'm using vlookup to relate item to price. I want to capture the sold price at that time and not take on the current value which might be affected by future updates.

Answer (score 0):

> File -> Spreadsheet Settings -> Calculation Tab -> Iterative
>   Calculation (Turn On)

Create a checkbox and name it with `Data->Named Ranges` (in my example I name it `freeze`)

```
if(freeze,indirect("RC",),
enter your formula here
)
```

Now when freeze is checked it will 'freeze' whatever data is in that single cell including vlookup.